# If I transfer brokerages for a taxable investment account, who is responsible for sending Form 1099s?

Tags: united-states, taxes, brokerage, form-1099, account-transfer

I am considering transferring brokerages for a taxable investment account. Will the new brokerage be responsible for sending me all Form 1099s for tax year 2013? Or is the old brokerage still responsible for part of the year? I have not sold any stocks yet this year so I think it is less complicated, but I have received dividends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each brokerage will send you 1099 for the transactions that occurred in its accounts.