# Who reports the dividend for ACTS transfer, Outgoing or Incoming brokerage?

Tags: united-states, dividends, form-1099, qualified-dividend

When a taxable brokerage account is transferred from one broker to another and as the old broker receives( and in turn forward to new broker) the dividend **after the transfer** as Dividend pay date is after the transfer, but ex-dividend date was before the transfer date.

So question is who report the dividend on 1099 for at the year end ?

Second question, as a dividend is considered **qualified-dividend** if stock is held for more than [60 days](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/q/qualifieddividend.asp)? How does the old broker will know that the stock was held for another 60 days?

> Common stock investors must hold the shares for more than 60 days during the 121-day period that starts 60 days before the ex-dividend date, or the date after the dividend.

Comment: See https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/20777/if-i-transfer-brokerages-for-a-taxable-investment-account-who-is-responsible-fo.

Comment: @craig-w thanks, what about qualified or non qualified dividend?

Comment: That aspect I'm not sure about, which is why I didn't mark your question as a duplicate.

Comment: **It's new-broker** who pays _you_ and should report that, and new-broker knows your holding period (unless you bought _and_ transferred within 60 days of year end so as of 1099 preparation it isn't determined yet). I _think_ old-broker gets a pass on reporting transfer to new-broker because they're regulated, but even if not it doesn't affect you.

Comment: @dave-thompson-085 thanks, I hope brokerages does not mess up the 1099, they seem to be correting it at any time  https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/107968